# Mock class in Angular using Jest

Tags: angular, typescript, jestjs

I have been struggling for a long time with trying to mock one function I want to test. I have been reading the Jest documentation and I'm sure the answer probably is there somewhere but I just can't but the pieces together to make it work. I also couldn't find any previous question that made me solve my issue as many of the ones I looked into seems a bit outdated.

This is the function I'm trying to test (a bit simplified):

```
export function getOrganizationAdministrationLinks(permissions: RolePermission[], features: FeatureEnum[],
    translateService: CustomTranslateService): Array<{ name: string, target: string } | 'divider'> {
const uiLinks = new Array<{ name: string, target: string }>();
const organizationLinks = new Array<{ name: string, target: string }>();
const tradingLinks = new Array<{ name: string, target: string }>();

if (havePermissionsAndFeatures(permissions, features, OrganizationSettingsPermissions.permissions, OrganizationSettingsPermissions.features)) {
    uiLinks.push({ name: translateService.get('something'), target: 'interface' });
}

return [uiLinks, organizationLinks, tradingLinks]
    .filter(group => group.length > 0)
    .flatMap(group => [...group, 'divider' as const])
    .slice(0, -1);
```

The dependency I'm having issues with is the `CustomTranslateService` one. It looks like this:

```
export class CustomTranslateService {

public onLangChange: EventEmitter<LangChangeEvent>;

constructor(private readonly translate: TranslateService,
            private readonly userBrowserStateService: UserBrowserStateService) {
    this.onLangChange = this.translate.onLangChange;
    this.setCulture(this.userBrowserStateService.getCulture());
}
/**
 * Returns a translation for the translation key & params.
 */
public get(key: I18nKey): string {
    if (typeof key === 'string') {
        return this.translate.instant(key);
    } else {
        return this.translate.instant(key.key, key.params);
    }
}
```

The part I'm struggling with is that when calling `getOrganizationAdministrationLinks` which is the function I want to test, I have to pass a `CustomTranslateService`. The `CustomTranslateService` itself has dependencies and I can't figure out how to mock this. I suspect that I might have to mock it manually but it feels a bit overkill since I just want to mock the return call of the `get` method.

I'm only using `jest` and `jest-preset-angular` packages. I've seen some suggestions of using `ts-jest` but I'm not sure if it's needed. Also I'm on Angular 12.0.2 and TypeScript 4.1.3.

Comment: _"The `CustomTranslateService` itself has dependencies and I can't figure out how to mock this"_ - the point of using a test double for the collaborator is that you don't have to care what its dependencies are, you isolate what you're actually testing from it. Why not just e.g. `useValue: { get: () => 'something translated' }` as the test double?

Comment: @jonrsharpe But i still need to pass CustomTranslateService to the getOrganizationAdministrationLinks-function in my test, and this requires an instance of the CustomTranslateService?

Comment: No it doesn't, it just requires something that can play that role. Angular has its own DI system to help you with this, or in this case you just pass it as an argument.

Comment: @jonrsharpe The part about passing it as an argument is where is struggle. How do i get an object that i can pass? All the examples i see is just mocking a class without getting an instance that can be used to pass to the method?  Thanks.

Comment: `getOrganizationAdministrationLinks([], [], { get: () => 'something translated' } as CustomTranslateService)`?

Comment: That gives me -> "Conversion of type '{ get: () => string; }' to type 'CustomTranslateService' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.
  Type '{ get: () => string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'CustomTranslateService': onLangChange, translate, userBrowserStateService"

Comment: OK, and that _was_ intentional - you're creating a test double, the thing you're testing doesn't use those other properties (and according to the definition you've shown, `translate` and `userBrowserStateService` are private anyway). Read e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/69771198/3001761 for some of the other options around type-safe test doubles.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks alot for ur help. I decided to go with creating a partial of the translateService.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a basic test with the solution for what i wanted to achive:

```
    test('getOrganizationAdministrationLinks should return correct name and target when called with rolePermissions and features', () => {
    const expected = [{
        name: 'overruns',
        target: 'interface'
    }];

    const translateService: Partial<CustomTranslateService> = { get: () => 'overruns' } ;
    const actual = getOrganizationAdministrationLinks(rolePermissions, features, translateService as CustomTranslateService);

    expect(actual).toEqual(expected);
});
```

Thank you @jonrsharpe for the general help and the link!